# Linear transformation whose $n$th power is identity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, field-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$ with $\dim_FV=2$. Suppose $T:V\longrightarrow V$ is a linear transformation with $T^n=Id$ for some positive integer $n$ (the finite $n$ is the order of $T$).

(i) If $F=\mathbb{Q}$, prove that $n\leq 6$.

(ii) For any integer $N$, prove that there exists a finite field $F$ with a non-diagonalizable $T$ of order larger than $N$.

I have totally no way to solve this question. Do not know where to start...

Answer (score 4):

First, you should be clear that $n$ is taken the smallest value${}>0$ possible for a given $T$; otherwise for $T=Id$ one could easily take $n=7$ or more. Then think what it means that $T$ has a minimal polynomial that divides $X^n-1$ but not any $X^m-1$ for $0<m<n$, and what can be the degree of that minimal polynomial.

Finally for the second question, compute what happens to powers of triangular matrices with diagonal entries$~1$ in characteristic$~p$.